# How to run a script in a OpenVPN server hosted in pfSense when client connects?

Tags: openvpn, scripting, pfsense

I've got an pfSense 2.6 instance which hosts OpenVPN for clients. I'm testing with client version OpenVPN Connect 3.3.7 (2979).

There are some web endpoints with a dynamic IP addresses, so I can't push the routes easily via `Custom options`. I also don't want to redirect all the traffic via the VPN either.

I found out about `allow-pull-fqdn`, but that's not supported by OpenVPN connect versions 3.x, source: https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3/issues/195

I'm now searching how to create a script to resolve DNS record and push the IP into client configuration.

**The first option** would be the best if the OpenVPN server would resolve the DNS record and push the route via script or some other means, because then I would not need to care about scripts on the clients.

Is there a way to do it like this?

**The second option** is to run a script on the clients. The client OS's can be Windows, Macs and Linux, so there's need to maintain different scripts.

I've been looking into `client-connect` option, but I can't seem to get it to work at all.
I wrote a batch file `vpn_push_routes.bat`

```
echo 'test' > C:\Users\user\Documents\test.txt
```

I've added these lines into the client config file:

```
script-security 3
client-connect C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\vpn_push_routes.bat
```

The OpenVPN Connect shows in the log that the lines are listed as `UNUSED OPTIONS`

```
[Mar 8, 2023, 18:27:20] UNUSED OPTIONS
1 [persist-tun]
2 [persist-key]
3 [data-ciphers] [AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:CHACHA20-POLY1305:AES-256-CBC]
4 [data-ciphers-fallback] [AES-256-CBC]
6 [tls-client]
8 [resolv-retry] [infinite]
10 [nobind]
14 [auth-nocache]
20 [script-security] [3]
21 [client-connect] [C:\Users\user\Documents\vpn_push_routes.bat]
```

I'd be also okay with the second option. Could somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the issue with **2nd** option was that the client being used was **OpenVPN Connect 3.3.7**. Documentation seems to be sparse how to use it with extra options.

With client version **OpenVPN Community 2.6.1** the script worksby adding the below lines into client config file. Here's the [reference manual](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-6/) for version 2.6.

```
script-security 2
up 'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\vpn_push_routes.bat'
```